# Backgound service or webservers of Ansible?

Tags: nginx, ansible, webserver, chef-infra

is there any background service or webservers that are used by ansible? like chef we have background services like nginx, solar, rabbit. is ansible use any webservers or background services?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by background ?? Is it regards to accessing ansible via UI ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no services required other then ssh on the target server. Some modules might require specific librarys installed (most often encountered with community supported modules)

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/overview_architecture.html#ansible-architecture

> It uses no agents and no additional custom security infrastructure, so it’s easy to deploy